# How to mock dependency of service that has fuction with argument in type of 'async Function'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I have a function here that is for getting the logs in the queue. How can I **mock** this function for unit testing ?

```
void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, IServiceProvider, Task> workItem);
```

```
Mock<IBackgroundTaskQueue> _Mock= new Mock<IBackgroundTaskQueue>();
```

```
_Mock.Setup(x=>x.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(?)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure you mean Function instead of Fucntion

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please provide a [mre] with sample setup and describe the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to mock such method, if you are not testing a specific parameter, is to use an `It.IsAny`:

```
_IBackgroundTaskQueueMock.Setup(x => x.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(It.IsAny<Func<CancellationToken, IServiceProvider, Task>>()));
```

Comment: This will not compile AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, now it's better.

Answer (score 1):

`QueueBackgroundWorkItem` returns `void` so just setup with `It.IsAny`:

```cs
_Mock.Setup(x => x.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(It.IsAny<Func<CancellationToken, IServiceProvider, Task>>()));
```